# Why is Java HashMap slowing down?

Tags: java, hashmap, bufferedreader

I try to build a map with the content of a file and my code is as below:

```
    System.out.println("begin to build the sns map....");
    String basePath = PropertyReader.getProp("oldbasepath");
    String pathname = basePath + "\\user_sns.txt";
    FileReader fr;
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> snsMap = 
            new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>(2000000);
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(pathname);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line; 
        int i = 1;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("line number: " + i);
            i++;

            String[] strs = line.split("\t");
            int key = Integer.parseInt(strs[0]);
            int value = Integer.parseInt(strs[1]);
            List<Integer> list = snsMap.get(key);
            //if the follower is not in the map
            if(snsMap.get(key) == null) 
                list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            list.add(value);
            snsMap.put(key, list);
            System.out.println("map size: " + snsMap.size());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("finish building the sns map....");
    return snsMap;
```

**The program is very fast at first** but gets much slowly when the information printed is :

```
 map size: 1138338
 line number: 30923602
 map size: 1138338
 line number: 30923603 
 ....
```

I try to find to reason with two System.out.println() clauses to judge the preformance of BufferedReader and HashMap instead of a Java profiler.
Sometimes it takes a while to get the information of the map size after getting the line number information, and sometimes, it takes a while to get the information of the line number information after get the map size. My question is: which makes my program slow? the BufferedReader for a big file or HashMap for a big map?

Comment: Why twice to call `get`? Don't put existing list to map.

Comment: Use a profiler, and you won't have to guess what is slow and what is fast...

Comment: how many number of lines are there in your text file?

Comment: remove the System.out.println from the while loop and try again.

Comment: You are assuming that the hashmap is slow, in reality it is probably the calls to println which are slowing you down.

Comment: The map has over 1.1m LinkedLists in it.  Are you running out of memory?

Comment: Remove the  System.out.println then I don't know what's going on... @Ameoo

Comment: @jerry_sjtu You can just reduce printing, not eliminate it. You can print every 1000 iterations, for example.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it can not be objectively answered with the information given, as evidenced by the speculation in all answers. To efficiently pinpoint Java performance problems, using a profiler (or something like profiling such as thread dumps) is by far the best way.

Comment: @meriton But giving good speculation is nevertheless useful, isn't it? Giving a useful answer is what SO is all about.

Comment: That's why I didn't downvote your answer; my issue is with the question. A "slow" HashMap can have a myriad of causes, even if it is the HashMap that is slow. If somebody else experiences the same symptoms, the cause might very well be different, perhaps not even listed here. Consequently, what was a useful answer this time might be mere noise for the next visitor.

Comment: anyway, speculating some more, you could declare that String[] strs from loop, outside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are testing this from inside Eclipse, you should be aware of the **huge** performance penalty of writing to stdout/stderr, due to Eclipse's capturing that ouptut in the Console view. Printing inside a tight loop is always a performance issue, even outside of Eclipse.

But, if what you are complaining about is the slowdown experienced after processing 30 million lines, then I bet it's a memory issue. First it slows down due to intense GC'ing and then it breaks with `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: See my reply on how to cut down the memory use by an estimated factor of 5-10, by using GNU Trove primitive collections. Roughly estimated, a `HashMap<Integer, List<>>` needs at least 3*16 bytes per entry. The doubly linked list again needs at least 2*16 bytes per entry stored. 1m keys + 30m values ~ 1 GB. No overhead included yet. With GNU trove `TIntObjectHash<TIntArrayList>` that should be 4+4+16 bytes per key and 4 bytes per value, so 144 MB. The overhead is probably similar for both. Definitely 5-10x less.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse You should really include all this fine information in your answer, make it more visible. Besides, why advertise your answer below mine, when your answer is plain in sight on this page.

Comment: Well, it is not obvious from a comment that another answer here may point out how to use less memory. I'll add the memory estimates to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to check you program with some profiling tools to understand why it is slow.
In general file access is much more slower than in memory operations (unless you are constrained in memory and doing excess GC) so the guess would be that reading file could be the slower here.

Comment: But the program is very fast at first and slow down after a while. I try to find the problem with the System.out.println(). @AKJ

Comment: Sometimes the act of measuring the program changes the program's characteristics.  And by measuring, I mean System.out.println(). Use a profiler; it's meant for this.

Comment: It is a *known fact* that heavy use of `System.out.println` has a major performance impact. Standard output is not good for debugging performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

**Before you profiled, you will not know what is slow and what isn't.**

Most likely, the `System.out` will show up as being the bottleneck, and you'll then have to profile without them again. `System.out` is the *worst* thing you can do for finding performance bottlenecks, because in doing so you usually add an even worse bottleneck.

An obivous optimization for your code is to move the line

```
snsMap.put(key, list);
```

into the `if`  statement. You only need to put this when you created a *new* list. Otherwise, the put will just replace the current value with itself.

Java cost associated with `Integer` objects (and in particular the use of Integers in the Java Collections API) is largely a memory (and thus **Garbage Collection**!) issue. You can sometimes get significant gains by using primitive collections such as **[GNU trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/)**, depending how well you can adjust your code to use them efficiently. Most of the gains of Trove are in memory usage. Definitely try rewriting your code to use `TIntArrayList` and `TIntObjectMap` from GNU trove. I'd avoid linked lists, too, in particular for primitive types.

Roughly estimated, a `HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>` needs at least 3*16 bytes per entry. The doubly linked list again needs at least 2*16 bytes per entry stored. 1m keys + 30m values ~ 1 GB. No overhead included yet. With GNU trove `TIntObjectHash<TIntArrayList>` that should be 4+4+16 bytes per key and 4 bytes per value, so 144 MB. The overhead is probably similar for both.

The reason that Trove uses less memory is because the types are specialized for primitive values such as `int`. They will store the `int` values directly, thus using 4 bytes to store each.

A Java collections `HashMap` consists of many objects. It roughly looks like this: there are `Entry` objects that point to a key and a value object each. These *must* be objects, because of the way generics are handled in Java. In your case, the key will be an `Integer` object, which uses 16 bytes (4 bytes mark, 4 bytes type, 4 bytes actual `int` value, 4 bytes padding) AFAIK. These are all 32 bit system estimates. So a single entry in the `HashMap` will probably need some 16 (entry) + 16 (Integer key) + 32 (yet empty LinkedList) bytes of memory that all need to be considered for garbage collection.

If you have lots of `Integer` objects, it just *will* take 4 times as much memory as if you could store everything using `int` primitives. This is the cost you pay for the clean OOP principles realized in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to run your program with profiler (for example, JProfile) and see what parts are slow. Also debug output can slow your program, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Hash Map is not slow, but in reality its the fastest among the maps. HashTable is the only thread safe among maps, and can be slow sometimes.

Important note:  Close the BufferedReader and File after u read the data... this might help.

eg:  br.close()
     file.close()

Please check you system processes from task manager, there may be too may processes running in the background.

Sometimes eclipse is real resource heavy, so try to run it from console to check it.